# How to have each div neadly next to each other without any space between them

Tags: css, css-grid

I am new to grids and trying to understand how they work. The code below I copied directly from [MDN - Css grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout). Can someone help me with removing the white-space wrapped around each div so they could be neatly stacked like the target structure? Any help would be appreciated!"

- [Target grid layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/696Uv.png)
- [My outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezeLx.png)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 500px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
  width: 40%;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: green;
}

.four {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
  width: 30%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.five {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4;
  width: 30%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: purple;
}

.six {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 4;
  width: 30%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">Six</div>
</div>
```

I tried to add width and height for each `div` but got the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the width and height like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 500px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  gap: 20px; /*You can remove this gap if you don't want space between them.*/
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
}

.two {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 3;
  background-color: green;
}

.four {
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 3 / span 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.five {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 4 / span 1;
  background-color: purple;
}

.six {
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
  grid-row: 4 / span 1;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div class="six">Six</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Followed your suggestion. I clicked the Run code snippet button, and the result was exactly like what I wanted but when I  plugged the code into my code, it turned out like this
- [My new outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x58Lm.png).

Comment: Do you have any more class or css library who is modifying your code?

Comment: I had `margin: auto;` set up in the wildcard, and that was the reason. 
I have my issue solved.
Thank you for your help. @mgm793